# ¿Como obtener registros de wordpress y exportarlos en un .csv con php?

Tags: php, json, array, wordpress

He estado intentando obtener la informacion de los usuarios de una base de datos de wordpress y exportala en un archivo .csv

Este es el codigo que estoy utilizando:

```
<section>
    <div>
            <?php
            $array_export_cvs = array();
            $array_export_cvs[] = array("Correo", "Nombre", "Cedula", "Departamento", "Ciudad", "Fecha de nacimiento");
            $args = array('role' => 'subscriber');
            $current_user = get_users( $args );
                foreach($current_user as $user){
                    $full_name = get_user_meta($user->ID, 'pie_text_4', true) .' '. get_user_meta($user->ID, 'pie_text_3', true);
            $cedula = get_user_meta($user->ID, 'pie_text_36', true);
            $departamento = get_user_meta($user->ID, 'pie_text_11', true);
            $ciudad = get_user_meta($user->ID, 'pie_text_12', true);
                    $fecha = get_user_meta($user->ID, 'pie_date_9', true);
                    $fecha = $fecha[date]; 
                    $array_export_cvs[] = array($user->user_email, $full_name, $cedula, $departamento, $ciudad, $fecha);
                    echo(json_encode($array_export_cvs));
                }           
            $fp = fopen('fichero.csv', 'w');
            foreach ( $array_export_cvs as $line ) {
                fputcsv($fp, $line,';');
            }
            fclose($fp);
            ?>
        <a class="btn btn-default" href="/fichero.csv" download="fichero.csv">Download</a>
    </div>
</section>
```

Hasta el momento el codigo me funciona bien y me genera el siguiente array:

```
["usuario@email.com","Usuario Prueba","145127843","Departamento2","Ciudad3",["14\/10\/1991"]]
```

Sin embargo al ver el archivo .csv generado me encuentro con lo siguiente:

```
usuario@email.com;"Usuario Prueba";145127843;Departamento2;Ciudad3;Array
```

La fecha de nacimiento esta generando algun tipo de error y en el archivo generado aparece simplemente la palabra "Array".

Alguien tiene conocimiento de que podria estar fallando?
Muchas gracias a los que me puedan colaborar.

Comment: prueba con:
implode($fecha); 

http://php.net/manual/es/function.implode.php

Comment: @Dr.Manhattan con el implode, Sigue mostrando lo mismo.